# Is every convex function differentiable amost every where?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

If a function $f: D \subset R^n \rightarrow R$ is convex, then for every $x,y \in D$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$, 
$$
f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y) \leq \alpha f(x) + (1 - \alpha)f(y).
$$

I konw a convex function is a continuous function.

I just wonder if every convex function is differentiable amost every where.

This is important, because one of the most important way to solve a convex problem is gradient decent.

Comment: I believe there is a result that any strictly increasing function is differentiable almost everywhere. Try to use that.

Comment: Convex functions are locally Lipshitz, thus is differentiable almost everywhere. Actually, a convex function is twice differentiable almost everywhere.