# How can I prove that the set of nondifferentiable points of a convex function is countale?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am just reading brownian motion and stochastic calculus by Ioannis Karatzas and Steven Shreve and came up with this problem. Any help would be valuable.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031571/is-every-convex-function-differentiable-amost-every-where

Comment: well does it mean then that having countable set of nondifferentiable points and being differentiable almost everywhere is the same?

Comment: i guess not because being differentiable almost everywhere means that the lebesgue measure of the set of nondifferentiable points is 0 which doesnt mean that the set is countable

Comment: Your comment is right: the Cantor set has measure 0 but is uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

**Sketch of proof.** The left and right derivatives $f_-'$, $\,f_+'$ of a convex function $f$ do exist, and they are both increasing, and also
$$
f_-(x)\le f_+'(x), \quad\text{for all $x$}.
$$
Thus each of them is discontinuous in a countable at most set $S$, and they differ in a subset of $S$.

Comment: where can i find the detailed proof?

Comment: I do not know. But, the first thing to understand is why monotonic functions are discontinuous at most in countably many points.

Comment: i think the best way to show that is that the set where right and left hand derivatives are different is made up of rational numbers and because the set of rational numbers is countable such set will be countable too. it has to do something with the subderivative of a convex function

Comment: I believe there is a small mistake, it should say $f_-'(x) \le f_+'(x)$